# Global matching of 3D point clouds

Tags: 3d, matching, point-clouds, halcon

There are many kinds of ways of point clouds matching. for example, ICP, pcl's matching of ppf or something else. But most of them are matching one target to one source (one by one).

Now I have a case is that I have one pointcloud with a bottle as model, and the other pointcloud is lots of bottles as scene. I want to match the model to the scene and get not only one result of objects(one by many).

I find a api in MVTEC, this is exactly what I need, but it is payable.

[image]

You can see on the left of the photo is the real secene and the right side is pointcloud.
I want to find "many of bottles" in scene pointcloud of using one model pointcloud.

I know there's some ways of declaring global counterpoint, but all of them can just match one result in scene, not what I want that get multiple result.

Is there any idea or implementation method is open source or in any paper?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a surface matching module here:

[OpenCV Surface Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html)

The algorithm is based off of Bertram Drost's point pair features. The method in Halcon is also based off point pair features. You should beware that the method is patented by MVTec.

Beyond this I would check out some of the papers from the latest BOP challenge (Benchmark for 6D Object Pose Estimation). Some of the ones based off deep learning are starting to show results similar to the methods found in Halcon.

[BOP Challenge](https://bop.felk.cvut.cz/challenges/)